# how to make aws prompt colored

Tags: bash

I'm using ssh for ec2 instance but the colour for prompt is plain `ubuntu@ip-11-2-2-44:`

I can't seem to understand this. Can anyone tell me how do I fix this? Make it coloured or something. It's mixing with rest of the text in terminal

Answer (score 1):

You can customize the prompt by configuring your PS1 environment variable in your shell profile (typically your .bashrc or .zshrc).

Ubuntu provides documentation for this here: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CustomizingBashPrompt.